# Glassfish 7.0.12 adds question mark to URL when running JAVA EE Application

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am struggeling with my first "real" WebServer-Project at a certain point. Up to now I always used Nodejs-servers. But as I want to involve my own MySQL-Database I decided to use a plain JAVA-backend this time.

The backend runs with a JAVA EE (JAVA 17) Project on Glassfish 7.0.12 on a virtual Ubuntu Server hosted by a provider on the internet. The backend is hidden behind a NGINX-Server that is used as a https proxy. I do this with all my servers and this is the fourth now running on the same Linux server.

The frontend is built with Angular 16.x and provides currently only a landing page and 2 buttons which are supposed to simply call 2 backend services, the way I would do it in a browser's address field or with Postman.

I managed to deploy the app on the glassfish server and I can call the landing page via https. No problems so far.

I can effortlessly call the 2 implemented backend services when calling them via Postman or simply the browser's adress field. All works as expected.

But as soon as I klick one of the buttons the UI flickers for a blink of an eye and then reloads the entire landing page. Looking at the browser console showed me, that there occurs a **NS_BINDING_ABORTED** error.

So I investigated a little more using the console and found out that, differing from my other projects, the field "Referer" in the http header looks like this

**https://my-domain/my-context-root/?**

Where does this question mark at the end come from? I guess that this might be the key to the solution. Because neither of my other landing pages come up with this appendix.

If I understand CORS right, then this referrer is used to apply the same-origin rule. And as there is one unnecessary character the comparison fails.

Does anybody know where this question mark comes from and how I can remove it?

This is my browser console after the error

[image: This is my browser console after the error]

This is what my index.html looks like

[image: This is what my index.html looks like]

Here comes the CORS-related backend code. I only added this filter when I tried to fix the issue but it did not help at all, as it seems that the call does not even leave my browser.

```
package org.my-app_server.base;

import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CorsResourceFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    }

}
```

And here is where I call this at the server's start

```
package org.my-app_server.base;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RRSSApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

        resources.add(CorsResourceFilter.class);

        return resources;
    }

}
```

Comment: hey, what Angular version are you using? the question makr may come from the default of Angular routes

Comment: Angular 16.2.0.
But no other of my projects, and all are based on Angular 16.2.0, shows this behavior. So my only assumption is, that this has something to do with the glassfish web server or somehow with the JAVA-Libs I have to use.

Comment: the question mark issue may come from your frontend bc Angular 16 and older, by default, often add a trailing question mark to route URLs when there are no parameters or query strings present. but it looks like not the only issue, the NS_BINDING_ABORTED error may be related to the CORS. could you share a bit of your backend code? especially CORS-related?

Comment: Hi, I added the code fragments to my description. -- When I set all up I had no CORS-related code at all. Approx. 3 hours ago I added these two blocks of code to my backend, following some solutions here on stackoverflow. But it did not change a thing.

Comment: Your CORS filter configuration seems correct...
It will seem silly, but this information('But as soon as I klick one of the buttons the UI flickers for a blink of an eye and then reloads the entire landing page.') may indicate an unintended request without a specific path (resulting in the question mark) and may be breaking the backend as it does not pass validation.
Check the 'button click' settings to ensure they are performing as expected. It also checks access from the frontend to the backend, there may be a request breaking during validation.

Comment: Nope. I do everything as I always did. The only thing that is different is, that I now use a glassfish server instead of a nodejs server. I also now managed to change the context root to just '/'. But this does not change thing. The call does not leave the PC as the browser or something else has something against it. I'll investiage further.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It had nothing to do with Glassfish at all.

I had my buttons inside a

```
<form> </form>
```

tag.

And Angular tried to transmit the form directly after pressing one of the buttons. This lead to an immediate reload of the entire app and thus the request was dropped before getting processed properly...